# Bootstrap modal not rendering inside ASP.NET main form

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am trying to pull values entered by a user from a C# code file using a Bootstrap modal, which is in an ASPX page.

I found that Bootstrap is not allowing two forms in one page (blocking values of another form), and as we all know, we have a master form in master page, so I can't use another form for the modal, and my modal is rendering outside of the main form.

I used this code to render my modal inside the parent form:

```js
function showDialog(id) {               
    $('#paiddialog').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
    });

    $('#' + id).modal("show");
}
```

This is the modal's HTML:

```html
<div id="paiddialog" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panels" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Update payment Information 

                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="form-field-1">
                                            Select Assignment ID
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlassignmentid" runat="server" DataTextField="iassignmentidref" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataValueField="iassignmentid" DataSourceID="sdassignmentid" CssClass="form-control">
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnbindassigdetails" runat="server" OnClick="btnbindassigdetails_Click" CssClass="btn btn-info">Pull info</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnupdate" OnClick="btnupdate_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success large">Request Payment </asp:LinkButton>

                        <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">
                            Close
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

The rendered HTML is some thing like this

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form id="mainform" action="page.aspx">
            <div class="pagecontent"></div>
        </form>
        <div class="model fade"></div>
</html>
```

But still no luck.

Comment: Can you provide any html on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any new readers, i managed to fix this by adding bellow script

```
$(this).parent().appendTo("form");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an ugly hack to allow another form tag.

```
</form><form action="blah.aspx" id="blah">
```

This will get a trailing form in there for you to work with. Not recommended but a way around the 1 form tag limit of .Net

Comment: Bootstrap only allowing one form in a page, if we add second form it is blocking other form controls

Comment: Yeah that hack really only works if the additional form you need is at the bottom of the page and you don't need any more webform controls. You CAN however use regular html form controls and do a regular post/ajax instead of the asp.net methods. Keep the modal at the bottom and you have that separation.